# Creating a set-builder for an unordered cartesian product, filtering out equal values on the subsets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wonder if the following set builder notation is correct:

$U(N_1, N_2, N_3) = \{\{a,b,c\} \mid a \in N_1, b \in N_2, c \in N_3\}$

The idea is that this creates a kind of unordered cartesian product, where by the definition of a set it is also possible to yield sets of cardinality $\le 3$ (in the set returned by $U$).

For instance, would:

$N_1 = \{2\}, N_2 = \{2\}, N_3 = \{3,4\}$

yield:

$U(N_1, N_2, N_3) = \{\{2,3\}, \{2,4\}\}$

My gut says that something goes wrong here, cause would the empty set also not be an element of each set $N_1,N_2,N_3$ and thus be included? I do not want this.

EDIT: I think I can just do this?

$C(N_1, N_2, N_3) = N_1 \times N_2 \times N_3 \\
U(N_1, N_2, N_3) = \{\{a,b,c\} \mid (a,b,c) \in C(N_1, N_2, N_3)\}$

Comment: Your first notation is just fine, though I find it difficult to tell from the way you've phrased it whether you want the empty set in your final set. As you've defined it, it would not be included in $U(N_1,N_2,N_3)$.

Comment: "would the empty set also not be an element of each set" No, the emptyset is a *subset* of each set.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I don't think it does work: if one of $N_1,N_2,N_3$ is empty then the whole $U(N_1,N_2,N_3)$ is empty.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - I can't tell from the question as posed that that is not the desirable outcome in that scenario. If we're making a "cartesian product" without ordering, it's just what one would expect. Perhaps the OP can clarify.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Oh I see - that's a very likely read, I'm not sure either now.

Comment: That's right - I don't want the empty set in it. As @NoahSchweber pointed out I confused what an empty set is (i.e. when it is a member of a set). It clears up things - thanks =) I do think that my edited notation is a bit more explicit, no?